# how to add fur to a high poly model for rust/unity?

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, unity

i'm trying to create a skin for rust, however, i've never dealt with fur textures before.

so far i have tried:

- quick fur via curve, joining it with the "exterior" high poly
- adding interpolate hair curves, creating a mesh and joining it with the "exterior" high poly
- hair tiling with a fur texture

the first two didn't work, bringing it into marmoset toolbag 4 to bake it did nothing. i'm still toying with the hair cards, however it's not giving me the effect i want it to.
ideally it's supposed to be a fur coat.

i'm still somewhat new to blender, so if there is an easier/more efficient way of doing this please let me know! or even link videos.
i want to do this in blender so i can have the texture/depth of the fur. people who have done similar did texturing strictly in substance painter, but i don't feel like substance would make it look realistic enough.

thank you[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to do? High-poly models don't work well in game engines (Unity) and millions of hair particles/curves to create fur don't work well either if you want to animate them in real-time. Hair cards are the better approach for game engines.